# Using nested async await function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a very simple code I'm trying to debug. I have an `async` function:

```
async function updateResult(event){

  let result = db.fetchResult(event.ProcessId);
  return result;

}
```

And I'm calling this from another simple `async` function:

```
exports.processEvent = async (event) => {
  try {

    let promises = [];


    const controls = await db.fetchControls(event.EventCode);
    
    if (controls) {     
      
       promises = controls.map((control) => {
         console.log(control);
         control.map(x => this.updateResult(event));
        
       });
           
     }

    return Promise.allSettled(promises);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

The problem is that in `exports.processEvent`, the content of `db.fetchControls(event.EventCode)` is executed to **completion** (a few logics and a db getItem call).

But the call to `db.fetchResult(event.ProcessId)` via `this.updateResult(x.Id, x.Version, event)` does NOT complete executing the **fetchResult** tasks (a few other logics a db GET call).

I feel like `fetchResult` returns prematurely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `Promise.all()`

Comment: is `fetchResult` itself an async or promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` is NOT promise-aware.  It does not wait for any of the promises in your callback to complete. So, in this piece of code:

```
control.map(x => this.updateResult(x.Id, x.Version, event));
```

It just runs through the entire array ignoring all the promises that are returned and thus NOTHING waits for those promises.

You can fix that by returning those promises to the higher level `.map()` which you are then awaiting with `Promise.all()`:

```
  promises = controls.map((control) => {
     console.log(control);
     return Promise.all(control.map(x => this.updateResult(x.Id, x.Version, event)));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. Being a noob here this solved the problem.